# Cartesian to Polar Form Integral $y = x^2$ from 0 to 1 Have Different Result

Tags: definite-integrals, area, polar-coordinates

I am trying to calculate the area $y = x^2$ from $0 \leq x \leq 1$, but I get the result is $1/3$. When I try to use polar then I get $r = \tan\left({\theta}\right)\cos\left({\theta}\right)$ from $0\leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

When I use $$A = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} (r)^2\:\mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan\left({\theta}\right)\cos\left({\theta}\right))^{2}\:\mathrm{d}x,$$ the result is $1/6$? Or is there any concept that I at fault with?

Comment: $r = \tan \theta \sec \theta$.

Comment: Actually, I realize that I was wrong writing my r. In my paper, it is written using sec, while here is cos. Maybe because it is my first time asking questions. Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

You've made multiple errors.

The conversion from cartesian to polar was not done correctly. $y = r\sin\theta, x = r\cos\theta$, so you should have ended up with $r = \sec \theta \tan\theta$ rather than what you got.

Next up, your variable of integration after conversion should be $\theta$ not $x$.

Finally, when you work out that (incorrect) definite integral that you wrote, you do *not* get $\frac 16$.

When you evaluate the correct integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac 12 r^2 d\theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac 12 \sec^2 \theta\tan^2 \theta$, you get the value $\frac 16$. The indefinite integral is $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 13 \tan^3\theta+c$, which evaluates to $\frac 16$ with those bounds.

This is in fact expected. If you did a sketch of exactly what area you were computing with each method, you'd realise that what you're getting with polar coordinates is the green area between the curve $y=x^2$ and $y=x$, but what the integration with cartesian coordinates gives is the yellow area. As expected the areas add up to the area of the right triangle bounded by vertices $(0,0); (1,0);(1,1)$, i.e. $\frac 13 + \frac 16 = \frac 12$.

Lesson to learn: always sketch the curve before you attempt the area computation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your correctness. I've made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @wisnupramoedya No worries, we're all here to learn. If my answer has helped you, consider accepting it so the question may be closed. If you need to clarify anything else you may ask.